# Most efficient way to assign a value of zero to multiple variables at once

Tags: python

I'm trying to initiate the variables at zero, so it currently looks like this

```
x1,y1,x2,y2=(0,0,0,0)
```

It works, but just seems  a little redundant. Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd usually do

```
x1 = y1 = x2 = y2 = 0
```

However, this hardly matters.  Both versions are easy to grasp at a single glance.

Answer (score 13):

That is effectively unpacking a tuple. You can do:

```
x1 = y1 = x2 = y2 = 0
```

**Just don't do this with mutable objects!**

Comment: For those who don't understand the warning, try this: `a=b=[]`, `a.append(1)`. Now, if you haven't seen this before: `b==[1]`.

Comment: Can I do this to set **attributes** of mutable objects, and edits later on to one will not affect the other? My hunch is that I can. For example, I might want to change the labels of two separate Pandas `DataFrame` objects using `df1.columns = df2.columns = ('a', 'b', 'c')`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally use Jon or Sven's answer for clarity, but as an alternate answer you can use `itertools` for this:

```
import itertools
x1,y1,x2,y2 = itertools.repeat(0,4)
```

The warning for mutable objects still applies!