# Pythonic way to set multiple variables to a value of false

Tags: python

I am looking to initially set the value of 3 variables to `False` within a class.

Is there a more pythonic way of doing this than:

```
a, b, c = False, False, False
```

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634190/most-efficient-way-to-assign-a-value-of-zero-to-multiple-variables-at-once

Answer (score 2):

Since `False` is conceptually a immutable singleton you can do

```
a = b = c = False
```